# Leela chess zero weight files

Tags: leela

I'm using Leela chess zero for a couple of days and found a couple of weight files [here](https://github.com/dkappe/leela-chess-weights). But what is the place to be for weight files? I can imagine that lc0's strength is determined by the weight file.

For example, as you can see [here](https://github.com/dkappe/leela-chess-weights/tree/master/weights), the project has a couple of weight files, which one should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weights for main networks are [here](http://lczero.org/networks/). The best weights depends on whether you are using a cpu or gpu. For cpu, the best weights file is probably [LD2](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/530486338236055583/587323650282225700/LD2.pb.gz) which is a small net trained off of data for t40. For strong gpus or longer searches, one of the recent t40 networks will be very strong.

Comment: I indeed need the cpu version of the weight file, but when I load that file I get the following error: `Weights file is the wrong version.` How can I fix that?

Comment: I think I might have linked the wrong file, not sure what was wrong with the other, but try the updated link.

Comment: Did that fix it?

Comment: Yes, just got it working. The issue was that I was using an old version of the lc0 code. Now switched to the master repo. But, with this new version, it was not building a backend. But thats fixed now and the weight files works, thnx!